# How to display data in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I m using report generator, so my data is following a format

[{1:20,2:30,3:40},{1:50,2:10,3:80},{1:70,2:30,3:60}]

hear 1,2,3... are keys and 20,30,40,... value 
so this data send frontend side and display in the table.

table format like

```
1 | 2 | 3
-----------
20| 30| 40
-----------
50| 10| 80
-----------
70| 30| 60
-----------
```

Hear 1,2,3,.. are table head() and other is data()

so how to show data this format.

HTML

```
<table id="example"style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr id = 'title'></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id = 'data'></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript Code

```
$("#title").html('');
$("#data").html('');
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
  $.each(value, function (key, value) {
     $("#title").append('<th>'+ key +'</th>');
  });
});
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
  $.each(value, function (key, value) {
    $("#data").append('<td>'+ value +'</td>');
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you pass the context to frontend?

Comment: in JSON format using ajax.

Comment: Okay! So response.data() is `[{1:20,2:30,3:40},{1:50,2:10,3:80},{1:70,2:30,3:60}]` and  you wanted to display that in the page using javascript right?

Comment: @RajaSimon yes right

Comment: Can you show us your javascript code that how far you tried?

Comment: update question @RajaSimon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
solution :

$(document).ready(function()
  {
      var data =[{1:20,2:30,3:40},{1:50,2:10,3:80},{1:70,2:30,3:60}];
      console.log(data);
      var th_data = 0; 
      $.each(data, function(index, value1) {
        var tr_str1  = '';
        var tr_str2  = '';
        $.each(value1,function(key,value)
        {
          if(th_data == 0)
          {
            tr_str1 = tr_str1+"<th>"+key+"</th>";
            tr_str2 = tr_str2+"<td>"+value+"</td>";
          }
          else
          {
            tr_str1 = tr_str1+"<td>"+value+"</td>";
          }
        });
        th_data = th_data + 1;
        if(th_data == 1)
        {
          $('table').append("<tr>"+tr_str1+"</tr>"+"<tr>"+tr_str2+"</tr>");
        }
        else
        {
          $('table').append("<tr>"+tr_str1+"</tr>"); 
        }
      });    
  });
```